# Get Selected Jstree node values JQuery

Tags: jquery, jstree

Hi i have problem with getting data of selected node of jstree model.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#preview').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.selected);
        console.log(data.selected.attr("text"));
    });
</script>
```

the first console log shows me "[js1_1]" or "[js1_2]" depending on the selected node. But The second log "undefined is not a function" ;/ I have tried many different ways but i failed to achieve getting node text(title) or any other info

I send list of models as json and it looks like this:

```
Public Class JsTreeModel
   Public Property text As String
   Public Property icon As String
   Public Property Id As String
   Public Property PId As String
   Public Property ParentId As String
   Public Property Status As Integer
End Class
```

anyone has solution ?

UPDATE jstree code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#WhenRemoving').toggle($('.RemoveCheckbox').is(":checked"));
    $('#WhenAdding').toggle(!$('.RemoveCheckbox').is(":checked"));

    $('#preview').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': '/TreeTest/TreePreview/',
                'data': function (node) {
                    return node;
                }
            }
        }
    }).bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        $(this).jstree("open_all");
    })
});
</script>
```

when i add this to my jstree i can see selected name node in html div

```
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var i, j, r = [];
        for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
            r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
        }
        $('#event_result').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
data.selected.attr("text")
```

try this

```
data.selected.text()
```

You can also get selected `jstree` node text with this :

```
console.log($("#preview").jstree("get_selected").text());
```

OR just bind `select_node.jstree` as shown

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (NODE, REF_NODE) {
        var a = $.jstree._focused().get_selected();
    }
```

Comment: when i bind in var i still get undefined error in javascript console

Answer (score 19):

None above worked for me.
This worked:

```
$(treeID).jstree().get_selected(true)[0].text;
```

Comment: i love it when wrong answers are selected as correct, and the correct ones aren't

Comment: This worked for me too. Probably accepted answer is working for old version. Your answer is worked for jsTree 3.3.4

Answer (score 3):

simple to get all selected ids use the below code

```
 var selectedData = [];
 var selectedIndexes;
  selectedIndexes = $("#jstree").jstree("get_selected", true);
  jQuery.each(selectedIndexes, function (index, value) {
          selectedData.push(selectedIndexes[index].id);
  });
```

now you have all the selected id's in the "selectedData" variable

Answer (score 0):

oh.. it's very easy 
instead of

> console.log(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).text)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add plugin:

   ```
   "plugins": ["changed"]
   ```
2. Code:

   ```
   $('#container').on('changed.jstree',function(e,data){ 
           alert(data.node.text); 
   });
   ```